# If $u$ has a weak time derivative, does it make sense for $f(u)$ to have a weak derivative where $f$ is a piecewise function?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, bochner-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain. I write $L^2$ instead of $L^2(\Omega)$ etc.

Let $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$ with weak derivative $u' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$.

Consider 
$$f(u(x,t)) = \begin{cases}
-1 &: u(x,t) \in (-\infty, -1)\\
u &: u(x,t) \in (-1, 1)\\
1 &: u(x,t) \in (1, \infty).
\end{cases}$$

We have $f(u) \in L^2(0,T;L^2)$. Does it make sense to talk of a weak derivative of $f(u)$? We could naively write

$$(f(u))' = \begin{cases}
0 &: u(x,t) \in (-\infty, -1)\\
u' &: u(x,t) \in (-1, 1)\\
0 &: u(x,t) \in (1, \infty).
\end{cases}$$
and then write this as $(f(u))' = \chi_{\{u \in (-1,1)\}}u'$ but I can't make sense of this.

Comment: The question is: Does your "supposed" derivative satisfies the conditions to be a weak derivative? Did you tried to verify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, a function
$$
f(\xi)\overset{\rm def}{=}
\begin{cases}
-1,\quad \xi<-1,\\
\xi,\quad \xi\in [-1,1],\\
1,\quad \xi>1,
\end{cases}
$$
is Lipschitz, and hence by theorem 2.1.11 from the textbook 
*"Weakly differentiable functions"* by W.P. Ziemer, 
given any $u\in  L^2(0,T;H^1)$, for Sobolev weak derivatives, 
holds the chain rule
$$
\partial_{x_k} f(u)=\partial_{x_k} (f\circ u)=f'(u)\cdot\partial_{x_k} u
$$
implying that a superposition $f(u)=f\circ u\in L^2(0,T;H^1)$, while
a superposition $f'(u)=f'\circ u\in L^{\infty}(0,T;H^1)$. Indicated
in the post just $f(u)\in L^2(0,T;L^2)$ is not enough for a distributional 
derivative $\partial_t$ to be correctly defined, which requires a rather 
more delicate approach than Sobolev weak derivatives $\partial_{x_k}$.
Namely, the chain rule 
$$
\partial_t f(u)=\partial_{x_k} (f\circ u)=f'(u)\cdot\partial_t u
$$
holds with the *R.H.S.* being a correctly defined product of a distribution 
$\partial_t u \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$ by a function $f'(u)=f'\circ u\in 
L^{\infty}(0,T;H^1)$, which correctly defines a distribution $\partial_t 
f(u)\in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$, with distributions understood here as functional-valued 
Bochner measurable functions $(0,T)\to H^{-1}\overset{\rm def}{=}
\bigl(H_0^1(\Omega)\bigr)^{\ast}$.

Comment: Thank you. I define a weak derivative of $w \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$ as $w' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$ satisfying $\int_0^T (w(t), \psi'(t))_{L^2} = - \int_0^T \langle w'(t), \psi(t) \rangle_{H^{-1}, H^1}$ for all $\psi \in C_c^\infty((0,T);H^1)$. This is equivalent to $$\int_0^T w(t)\phi'(t) = -\int_0^T w'(t)\phi(t)$$ for all $\phi \in C_c^\infty(0,T)$. Isn't this what you mean when you write "$\partial_t u$ is distribution"?

Comment: So what is the action of $\partial_t f(u)$, which you have said is a product of a function multipled by a weak derivative (or distribution)? I thought such products were only well defined if the function is smooth; in this case, the we would have $\langle f(u)\partial_t u, v \rangle := \langle \partial_t u, f(u)v \rangle$.

Comment: OK, I see the same action is well-defined when the product is in $L^\infty(0,T;H^1)$. Just wondering if you have a reference to this to some text? Because I have never seen it used before. Sorry for all the pings.

Comment: @studentX: **Q1.** $\dots$ for all $\psi\in C_c^{\infty}(0,T;H_0^1)$. This is a standard  approach, and this is what I mean. I just  prefer the PDE notation $\partial_t u$ instead. **Q2.** Distribution $\partial_t f(u)$ can be defined two-fold: first as a weak/distributional derivative like in **Q1**, second as a product like in my answer. Both define one and the same: this is exactly the chain rule that can be established using approximations $C^1$-smooth in $t$, which is a rather trivial technical question. **Q3.** There is no need to consider $f''$ that is absolutely out of question.

Comment: Ok, i understand we can define $\partial_t f(u)$ as in **Q1**. You say we can also write $\partial_t f(u) = f'(u)\partial_t u$, and this is an element of $L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$. By definition then, the RHS must be a map $[0,T] \to H^{-1}$. For **Q2** I was really asking: is it right to say that $\langle f'(u(t))\partial_t u(t), w(t) \rangle_{H^{-1}, H^1} = \langle \partial_t u, f'(u(t))w(t)\rangle_{H^{-1}, H^1}$, for all $w \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$. This is what I would expect. For **Q3**, I thought in order to have $f'(u) \in L^\infty(0,T;H^1)$, we need to consider $f''$ to consider $\nabla f'(u(t))$.

Comment: @studentX: Basically, this is what is called *Mathematical Folklore* (for details see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_folklore). That which is well known, though not yet to be found in textbooks. In the context of your question, almost everyting around a nonlinear superposition operator $f(u)=f\circ u$ looks most intricate for a beginner, and the following reference will definitely be helpful: http://www.ebay.com/ctg/Nonlinear-Superposition-Operators-95-Petr-P-Zabrejko-and-J-rgen-Appell-2008-Paperback-/70325059